# Deploying Different Configurations To Octopus Deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

I hope this isn't really obvious in the documentation as I can't find anything on it.  Basically we are just starting to try Octopus Deploy for our solution but the problem we have is that we have different configurations.  Simple story is that we have multiple build configurations and depending on the build configuration additional projects are built and the output copied to the bin directory of the website or windows service.  These dlls are then loaded by MEF and it adds additional functionality to our application specific for a customer.

We are using Visual Studio Online and starting to look at using the automated builds with Octopus Deploy as detailed here:  http://www.nobadthing.com/continuous-deployment-to-dev-with-tfs-and-octopus-deploy/

My question is how do we distinguish the nuget packages that are built based on configuration so that we can then then link these specific nuget packages to specific deployments in OctopusDeploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we've answered the question via support, but just in case you missed it:

> The possibly simplest solution to this issue would be to include all of the different dlls in the one package, but in a single folder, then on deployment you can create a PowerShell step to move the correct dll into the correct location for the specific customer.

In essence, you'd have one package with all the possible MEF extensions included. At deployment time, based on a variable in Octopus, you could then copy the appropriate DLL's to the appropriate place.

This approach fits with the philosophy of [building your binaries once](http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/build-your-binaries-once).